# PNP/SP not working in team context

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts, pnp, pnpjs

I have created the SPFX tab webpart with crud Operation in sharepoint list

Not working in Microsoft teams app

but this webpart working in sharepoint page because its getting SharePoint context

I am able to get pnp work by setup the web with absolute url like below

```
 import { Web } from "@pnp/sp/webs";


const web1 = Web("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/myweb");
```

But this solution is not good approach for multiple tennant

Is there any way to use pnp/sp work in team context without using absolute url

Comment: Are you using this web part in a Teams tab or in a Teams personal app? An SPFx web part running in a Teams tab has a SharePoint context (the backing site for the team), but an SPFx web part running in a Teams personal app does not.

Comment: I have used this web part as a team Spfx tab and Teams personal app but web part is getting Teams context instead of SharePoint context, when i use the Sharepoint page link embedded as teams tab then its working

Comment: Do you mean that relative URL would be same for all the tenant i.e. /sites/myweb and you don't want to hard code "https://tenant.sharepoint.com" part? in any case if you want to do CRUD operation URL of the Site and List is compulsory with any approach either graph api/rest api/pnp js

Comment: @KalpeshVaghela yes , you are right relative and absolute url , i am not able to get in team context in spfx tab in team